# Spring Security: не проходит тестирование

Tags: java, junit, spring-security

Я покрыл контроллеры правами, таким образом:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/role")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ALL')")
public class RoleController {
```

На методах преавторизации нет. При запуске приложения всё отлично работает.
Я скопировал в тестовый пакет SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig() {
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123").authorities("ALL");

        }
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "admin", authorities = {"ALL"})
public void save() throws Exception {
    result = mockMvc.perform(post(URL)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(asJson(roleDto)))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").exists())
            .andReturn();

    assertEquals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, result.getResponse().getContentType());
}
```

Пишет:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/role
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {"accountId":null,"roleType":null,"authorities":null,"clientAccounts":null,"clientClusters":null,"id":null}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Pragma=[no-cache], WWW-Authenticate=[Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"], Cache-Control=[no-store], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?